# Running python in read-only Docker container

Tags: python, docker, import, bytecode

I have a web app that I want to run using Docker container with nginx. As I know, it is suggested that I use read-only container for security purposes, but when I run my app on local machine, it always generates `__pycache__` folder. Will it be a problem when running in read-only environment? If yes, how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start Python with the `-B`argument:

```
python -B myscript.py
```

This turns off writing `.pyc` and `.pyo` files when you import `.py` files.

Alternatively, you set and environmental variable:

```
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
```

Comment: And if i use uWSGI or gunicorn? Will it affect efficiency?

Comment: The startup times might be a bit longer. But once imported, all modules are cached in `sys.modules` anyway.

Comment: And with gunicorn I have to use environmental variable?

Comment: Seems the best option.